# TinyMCE with Ajax: How to return POST response to display in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, tinymce

So, I can send a Post to my PHP program and it can send a response to a div on my HTML page. However, what I want to do is have this response display in the TinyMCE editor and NOT in the div area. How do I adapt my code to do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>getdata</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/plugin/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function post()
    {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var documentx= $('#texteditor').val();
    $.post('validate.php',{postdocument:documentx},
        function (data) 
        {
         $('#data-container').html(data);
        } );
    }   
</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="get-data-form" method="post">
            <textarea class="tinymce" id="texteditor"> </textarea>
            <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="post();" />    
        </form>


<div id="data-container"> </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the data is sent back via JavaScript just use the appropriate TinyMCE API to set the content:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

...placing it back into the underlying textarea won't do anything unless you remove and re-init the editor.

**EDIT**:  Please see this TinyMCE Fiddle for a fully working example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/aPfaab

Comment: I'm afraid that page on the TinyMCE page is as clear as mud to me. There is no proper explanation of anything. It is as useless to me as a chocolate teapot. It is probably written by people who are so familiar with the TinyMCE that they assume far too much and cannot imagine why people can't understand it. I often see this regarding things I do understand and I think "how the hell would someone who doesn't know about this understand it". I have, of course, looked at the site before but, unfortunately found it of little use. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @Brian what part of the documentation do you not understand?  You use `tinymce.get()` to reference the editor and then the `getContent()` call to insert HTML into the editor.  If you are struggling to get it to work perhaps you could create a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows what you are trying to do and people could help address issues in your code?

Comment: In keeping with your instructions I first removed the existing editor.
  tinymce.get('texteditor').remove(); 
Then a simple 'init' creates a new one
  tinymce.init({
   selector: 'textarea', 
   auto_focus: 'texteditor'
});
  
Then follows this, but what do I enter in place of 'data' in order to get the returned data from my PHP program to appear in the new editor and NOT in the div.?

 tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(data);

Comment: There is no need to `remove()` and `init()` the editor - assuming the editor is already on the page you can do something like `tinymce.get('texteditor').setContent('<p>This is the new content</p>');` - except you would insert the HTML you grabbed from the server and not the hard coded string in my example.

Comment: I've tried this with and without remove/init. I tried a similar setContent command even before I made my first post. I was able to post new content but NOT my returned data. I've tried entering all sorts of combinations of stuff to replace '<p>This is the new content</p>', indeed I tried all this before my first post. I had no success. Try it, and I am sure you will find the same. I've also tried a delay before I execute the command. The problem could be due to where I placed the command, just before the closing bracket of the function post(), but that seemed to be the logical place to put it.

Comment: @Brian I added a TinyMCE Fiddle to my answer that is a fully working example of how to put POST data into the editor.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I tried your solution and what you have done does work but it is not a practical solution for several reasons.  It is not possible to send data from the form itself but only in the unconventional way shown, notwithstanding that  I have tried sending a reply from a PHP program both as simple text and with XML headers. Neither works.